# Asking for a word and checking its number of occurrence in a text file

Tags: java, text-files

```
public class Try{
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Try.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the subtring to look for: ");
    String Word=sc.next();
    String line=in.readLine();
    int count =0;
    String s[];
     do
     {
        s=line.split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i < s.length; i++) 
        {
            String a = s[i];
            if(a.contains(Word))
                count++;
        }
        line=in.readLine();
    }while(line!=null);
    System.out.print("There are " +count+ " occurences of " +Word+ " in ");
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Try.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
            String word = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print(word);
    }

  }
}
```

The intended purpose of my program is to ask the user for a certain word(s) that will be checked in a text file and if it exists, it will count the number of times the user-entered word occurs in the text file. So far, my program can only search for one word. If I try two words separated by space, only the first word will be searched and counted for its number of occurrence. Any tips on how to search multiple words?

Comment: What logic in the program would make you think it would search for multiple words? You only have a `if(a.contains(Word))` line, and an single counter. You will need to keep counters per entered word.

Comment: `String Word=sc.next();`  This means you're reading 1 word into a `String` named `Word`. Even if you were to alter this line, you would need to do more to ensure the two words you're looking for aren't adjacent. You can also run the debugger to check the contents of `Word` to see that it only contains one value. See [Scanner.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was following literally the title of the question and therefore I will suggest this algorithm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the subtring to look for: ");
    String word = sc.next();
    String line = in.readLine();
    int count = 0;
    // here is where the efficiently magic happens
    do {
    // 1. you dont need to split a line by spaces, too much overhead...
    // 2. and you dont need to do counter++
    // 3. do instead: calculate the number of coincidences that the word is
    //repeated in a whole line...that is what the line below does..
        count += (line.length() - line.replace(word, "").length()) / word.length();
    //the rest looks fine

    //NOTE: if you need a whole word then wrap the input of the user and add the empty spaces at begin and at the end...so the match will be perfect to a word

        line = in.readLine();
    } while (line != null);
    System.out.print("There are " + count + " occurences of " + word + " in ");
    }
```

---

## Edit:

if you want to check more than one word in the document then use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Test.txt"));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the subtring to look for: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    String[] word = input.split(" ");
    String line = in.readLine();
    int count = 0;
    do {
        for (String string : word) {
            count += (line.length() - line.replace(string, "").length()) / string.length();
        }

        line = in.readLine();
    } while (line != null);
    System.out.print("There are " + count + " occurences of " + Arrays.toString(word) + " in ");
}
```

Comment: This was a lot shorter but  it seems that the problem still persists. I tried entering two words yet only the first word's occurrence was recorded (using your algorithm). Any way to "fix"  that? Btw thank you for your suggestions :) Will definitely note those.

Comment: @REA98, I added an Edit section... this code should do what you are looking for..  please give a try and let me know...

Comment: I added just a few tweaks and it worked. Thank you very much :))

Comment: I have a last question, what would be that enhanced loop equivalent in a normal for loop? I've never used enhanced loop (it kinda confuses me)  so I really have a little idea on that part.

Comment: ummmm replace the hole loop for this 
***for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    count += (line.length() - line.replace(word[i], "").length()) / word[i].length();
   }***